# Old Dell inspiron mini 1012 sometimes not starting up, sometimes, and screen glitches

Tags: boot, dell-inspiron, zorin

We have a pretty old family laptop, currently with me, and I gave it to my sister for learning basic programming. Its a Dell Inspiron Mini 1012. I know it is too old, but learning basic programming should be Ok on it.
It has not been even powered on for 2-3 years or so... but I installed Zorin OS Lite a few months back and it worked great for hours then, even with WIndows XP (preinstalled on it), and now, it has started to act very weirdly.

Yesterday, booted up Zorin OS, using it, laptop suddenly went off, while connected to Power. Turning it back on resulted in a 7 beep code (which is a Processor failure signal for Dell). Tried everything, but no good. Searching led me to reseating RAM and especially, the CMOS battery. So I opened up the laptop following the Instructions, reseated RAM, Harddisk and the power cable, but I was unable to take off the CMOS battery cover, it was covered with a plate, and I couldn't find any instructions on the interenet how to remove it. So I put it back together, and now, suprisignly, the beep code disappeared, and laptop booted up normally into Zorin OS, until the whole screen glitched, and screen wasn't refreshing. I forced it off, let it charge to 100% while off.

Today morning, booted it into Windows XP, to check if that was working or not, and It was. After shutting down Windows XP, Pressing the Power button did nothing! Laptop's light was on, but screen was blank. I didn't force off this time and left it, After 30 mins or so LED went off. Booted it, and successfully booted into Zorin OS. I immediately did all the updates, and mid way, screen again glitched. After it turned off on its own ( 30 mins or so), it is again not turning on, only the LED is on.

It is in charge right now. Though the battery was newly replaced when it was last used (3~4 years), it discharged so quickly that I has to plug it in.

We really don't want to invest anything in this laptop now, but if it may work, then great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a pretty old good laptop indeed, The Release date is somewhere around 2010. I have been there. I have a nice Accer that also acted up like that one you have. Very likely the motherboard is either faulty or the screen is now showing signs of aging. I understand what you are doing but it will take a lot of time for you to figure out what was the problem and then you will see that it is not worth getting it fixed since you won't find either the motherboard or the screen contact or cables.

I would say that old laptops behave that way because they are old many things can go wrong so you can keep trying but it won't be stable and eventually will just die.

Just accept that it is the way it is and try to get a replacement not for the components but for the whole thing.

I hope this feedback will help you somehow.

Good job and I wish you a great day.

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly, that why I don't want to invest even a penny in this thing. Thanks!